# How can module TB trap $fatal from module A

Tags: simulation, system-verilog, rtl

I have an RTL simulation where module TB is the testbench for module A.

Module A generates $fatal when it meets some condition it doesnt like. 
Module TB generates/collects transactions to/from A. Is there a way I can trap $fatal or $error statements in module TB ?

I am looking to add a few lines in TB like

```
always @*
begin
  if (FATAL_CONDITION_SEEN) begin
     log("there was a problem");
  end
end
```

Ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

SystemVerilog has a `final` block that is triggered by the end of simulation

```
final begin
       log("there was a problem");
      end
```

You can have as many final blocks as you want, but like `initial` blocks, there is no guaranteed order among them. There are restrictions about what you can put in a `final` block, like no time consuming statements. See the [1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) LRM section **9.2.3 Final procedures**